# Does "SHELLEXECUTEINFO" for Lotus Script works in any windows OS? Does it also work in AIX, Linux and etc

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I just want to confirm regarding the "SHELLEXECUTEINFO" in lotus script. I believe it is for windows. Does it also works in Window Server 2003? I can't test it since I don't have the required machine and another thing will this work on AIX, Linux or other OS? (I think not) If ever it really would not work is there some alternatives (A Lotus Script Code that would run any file and would work on any OS)? Thanks.

Sample Codes:

```
' Use in Executing the Batch File or Exe File
Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As Long

Type SHELLEXECUTEINFO
    cbSize As Long
    fMask As Long
    hwnd As Long
    lpVerb As String
    lpFile As String
    lpParameters As String
    lpDirectory As String
    nShow As Long
    hInstApp As Long
    lpIDList As Long
    lpClass As String
    hkeyClass As Long
    dwHotKey As Long
    hIcon As Long
    hProcess As Long
End Type

Const SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS = &H40
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Declare Function ShellExecuteEx Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteExA" (lpExecInfo As SHELLEXECUTEINFO) As Long
Const SE_ERR_FNF = 2
Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Const INFINITE = &HFFFF
Const WAIT_TIMEOUT = &H102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "shell32.dll" and "kernel32.dll" are available in every Windows- System (32Bit and 64Bit), this will work for every Windows system.

And for the same reason, this code will not work for any AIX / Linux / other OS, as they do not know the dlls...

If you just want to execute something and NOT have to wait for its completion, then using the built in LotusScript "shell"- function is absolutely sufficient.

Unfortunately I have no example code for any other way of doing this in NON Windows OS

Comment: Hi Torsten, thanks for confirming it, I too believed it that way but I am not so sure since I haven't tested it. Now that I have confirmed it, do you have any idea where I can run a file using some lotus script code that will work on any OS? I included this question above, but it was not clear sorry. Thanks

Comment: Please check my edit. The "shell"- Command in LotusScript might help you

Comment: I check the shell command and .cmd (Can .cmd file be run in other OS) file is not included but ok let me try doing it. I hope it works, since in the executable file it would do other things and run something inside the system.. The cmd file does a ftp and run the file at the same time inside the the ftpied system. Thanks for the information torsten..

Lastly, this is the only way you know to run a executable file in any OS? Just to confirm. Thanks a lot.